# How to move dock items?

Tags: macos, dock, customization, contextual-menu

Options gives me

[image] (slack)

or

[image] (chrome)

but I don't get the options to rearrange the icons in the dock.  I can't 'drag' the item either.  How can I achieve this?

I am on yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a smooth click and upward motion on an icon using your mouse or trackpad to rearrange icons in the Dock. Don't click-and-hold, click and move -- if you click and hold you'll get the option menu overlay for the application.

Tried to make a little gyfcat that shows it happening:

http://www.gfycat.com/ClearcutUnluckyAndeancondor

This irregardless of the setting for `Keep in Dock` on the application. In the above example I'm moving apps that have `Keep in Dock` set and not set. They're all re-arrangeable.

Comment: Ah yes, click and quickly move, got it, thx!

Comment: After trying this I was soon inspired to learn how to turn on three-finger-drag instead. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/42473/277466

Answer (score 3):

One option was to uncheck 'Keep in Dock' (context-click) to remove it, then:
open the applications folder to find the program and then:
drag it to the new desired place in the dock.
Finally recheck Options -> 'Keep in Dock'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the follow worked:

- Launch "Launchpad"
- while Launchpad is open

  - remove the Icon you want to rearrange from the dock by dragging it upwards on the screen
  - re-add the Icon from the Launchpad list at the position you wanna have it

good luck.